# How to show IDs of objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a little application where I can write random stuff and then save it in SQLlite database file. Another Activity read those informations and show it in ArrayList. Then I created a button to delete first object of the list. Now I'm trying to change it a bit so the user can choose which object will be deleted. And it's working great as well. The problem is that I don't know how to show an IDs of objects from the list on the screen. Can you look at this code and help me?

onCreate in Activity where I shows my list:

```
    dbwrapper = new MyDatabaseWrapper(this);
    dbwrapper.open();
    myContactsList = dbwrapper.getAllContacts();

    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<myContact>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myContactsList));
```

getAllContacts function from MyDatabaseWrapper:

```
   public List<myContact> getAllContacts() {

            List<myContact> myList = new ArrayList<myContact>();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CONTACTS_TABLE, null);

            c.moveToFirst();

            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                    myContact mc = new myContact();
                    mc.setData(c.getInt(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2),
                                    c.getString(3));
                    c.moveToNext();
                    myList.add(mc);
            }
            c.close();
            return myList;
    }
```

And an class where I convert my values from database to string:

```
package com.example.sqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class myContact {

    String imie;
    String nazwisko;
    String tel;
    int id;

    public myContact() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setData(int _id, String i, String n, String t){

            id=_id;
            imie=i;
            nazwisko=n;
            tel=t;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

            return "[" + String.valueOf(id) + "]" + "\n" +
                            imie + "\n" +
                            nazwisko + "\n" +
                            tel;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }

}
```

It looks like that:
http://screenshooter.net/100009676/chxmipm
http://screenshooter.net/100009676/ngbxmgx

I deleted one object with number 3.

So yeah. So far the number in "[ ]" is the id from database. I want to change this number to ID of object.

Comment: Please don't post links to code. Copy the relevant code (as short as possible) to your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "ID of object"?

Comment: I mean location of the element in the list. So for example if I have:
1: A;
2: B;
3: C;
and I will delete object 2 with "B" then the list will be:
1: A;
2: C;
And these locations I want to show before "A" "B" "C" etc. (I want to show it in "[ ]" in my application).

Comment: Eran, I will edit my question ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do much android dev so I apologize that I may not fully understand this, but why can't you just use `indexOf(Object o)`? Wouldn't that be enough for you to get the ID of any given element, as long as you know the element itself? (which, assuming you want to delete it, you would)